# ArgumentException in WCF service in ASP.NET Web App while using WinRT API's

Tags: asp.net, wcf, windows-runtime, toast

Requirement is to show Toast Notifications from asp.net web application.

I have a WCF service hosted in my asp.net web app, where I'll receive responses from another web service. As and when I receive the response, I need to send a toast with some info.

To support toasts on traditional asp.net application, I did add "TargetPlatformVersion" tag with "10.0" in the .csproj file and there after I could add the references of "Windows.Data" & "Windows.UI" namespaces that are required to send Toasts.

Now in my WCF service code behind, I handled the response received and at last added new API ("UpdateToast") to send toasts, where I continuously getting Argument Exception at this caller itself.

Exception detail below:

> {System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

I tried adding displaying MessageBox construct in my "UpdateToast" API, and it works but once I include any WinRT API's, I get this exception.

I also tried sending toasts using same WinRT API's in a sample console application targeting .net framework only and it's working there, I only see this exception in asp.net application.

I couldn't get any clue as whether WinRT API's are not supported here in this context or whether I did messed up anything. Kindly help.

Comment: You do understand that this code runs on the web server, not on the client? And that a web server runs as a Windows Service, i.e. without a visible desktop?

Comment: Yes I know it is a web server that runs my code and is a windows service. As here I did hosted locally in IIS in my desktop and as it is running on windows platform, I expect any windows code to be able to run. In fact I thought this is possible as a simple Message Box is working but only the WinRT doesn't. Correct me if i'm wrong also. Kindly help how to achieve the above.

Comment: One more aspect is whatever I tried as said above is observed while running in debug directly from VS (hosted via IIS Express) and observed this exception.